# Centre buttons on a navigation menu [html/css]

Tags: html, css

Currently working on a nav menu for a web page, however, after reading through the code multiple times, I can't seem to force the buttons to the centre of the menu, whatever I do they either stick left or it just breaks the nav altogether.

at this point, my brain is just mush, I apologize if it's a bit messy, but any assistance on how I can get these buttons to be centred is appreciated. Have provided an image link below of how the menu currently looks.

[image]

```css
/* RESET */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nv {
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nv a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.snv {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.snv .snvbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nv a:hover,
.snv:hover .snvbtn {
  background: white;
  color: #3b7a8b;
}

.snv-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  center: 0;
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}

.snv-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.snv-content a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #3b7a8b;
}

.snv:hover .snv-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nv">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="snv">
    <button class="snvbtn">About </button>
    <div class="snv-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="snv">
    <button class="snvbtn">Services </button>
    <div class="snv-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="snv">
    <button class="snvbtn">Partners </button>
    <div class="snv-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `sub-parent` div inside `.nv` and apply `flexbox` just **2 lines**.

```css
.nv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

in your case I named it `.container`

```css
/* RESET */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nv {
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nv a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.snv {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.snv .snvbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nv a:hover,
.snv:hover .snvbtn {
  background: white;
  color: #3b7a8b;
}

.snv-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  center: 0;
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}

.snv-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.snv-content a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #3b7a8b;
}

.snv:hover .snv-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nv">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="snv">
      <button class="snvbtn">About </button>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <a href="#company">Company</a>
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
        <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="snv">
      <button class="snvbtn">Services </button>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
        <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
        <a href="#package">Package</a>
        <a href="#express">Express</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="snv">
      <button class="snvbtn">Partners </button>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is change your `.nv { display: inline-block }` to `display: flex`:

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper-body">

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>

      <style>
        body {
          font: normal normal bold 16px trebuchet ms;
          border: 0;
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        .nv {
          background: #4d9fb1;
          background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
          padding: 0;
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;
          text-decoration: none;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        
        .nv a {
          font-size: 16px;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: block;
          float: left;
        }
        
        .snv {
          text-align: center;
          float: left;
        }
        
        .snv .snvbtn {
          font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          background: inherit;
          font: inherit;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .nv a:hover,
        .snv:hover .snvbtn {
          background: white;
          color: #3B7A8B;
        }
        
        .snv-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          center: 0;
          background: #4d9fb1;
          background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
          width: inherit;
          z-index: 1;
          color: white;
        }
        
        .snv-content a {
          display: inline-block;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .snv-content a:hover {
          background: white;
          color: #3B7A8B;
        }
        
        .snv:hover .snv-content {
          display: block;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="nv">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <div class="snv">
          <button class="snvbtn">About </button>
          <div class="snv-content">
            <a href="#company">Company</a>
            <a href="#team">Team</a>
            <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="snv">
          <button class="snvbtn">Services </button>
          <div class="snv-content">
            <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
            <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
            <a href="#package">Package</a>
            <a href="#express">Express</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="snv">
          <button class="snvbtn">Partners </button>
          <div class="snv-content">
            <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>



    </body>

    </html>

  </div>
  <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```